# Why are pointers obtained by the address-of operator not lvalues?

Tags: c++, c

I'm interested to know why an assignment like `&a = &b` is not permitted in C++.

I understand the risks in doing so, but it's not a good enough reason to forbid it completely, to me at least. The reason why I thought about that was because I was looking for a smart way to swap big objects without copying, and something like that seemed like a good idea:

```
void ptr_swap( ptrdiff_t &a, ptrdiff_t &b )
{
    a = a ^ b;
    b = a ^ b;
    a = a ^ b;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 157648.13;
    double b = 96871.84;

    printf("%.4f %.4f\n", a, b);

    ptr_swap( reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(&a), reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(&b) );

    printf("%.4f %.4f\n", a, b);
}
```

.. but apparently, the compiler doesn't think so. :(

**EDIT:** I understand why this doesn't work. Maybe my question would be clearer like that: I don't know how many properties a variable has in a program, but at least a name, a value, an address, and some indication of its lifetime perhaps. The thing is that to me, swapping is essentially renaming two existing values stored in memory, and it's nonsense that it would incur a copy.

With this "horrific" code example that I gave up there, what I'm trying to do is to say to the compiler: "From now on, b is named a, and vice-versa". Why is such a thing not possible? The motivation is that it's already possible to "instruct the compiler" in a way, via TMP for instance, so why not like that too?

Comment: `&a` is the address of `a`, it's basically a number. `1 = 2;` wouldn't make sense either, would it?

Comment: If 1 and 2 are variables (which I'm asking why they're not here), then yes it makes sense.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn - You need to read up on pointers...

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: But they *aren't* variables. They're numbers. That's what a pointer is; a number.

Comment: Your `ptr_swap`, by the way, is a terrible idea. Always swap using a temporary, that results in the best code. The compiler understands that. And the xor swap will annihilate your value if you pass it pointers to the same place.

Comment: @Lee Taylor: I know about pointers, my question is why & returns a temporary, and not a variable?

Comment: Because, as others have already said, it's not a variable. It's a temporary value. `a` is the variable; `&a` is as much of a temporary as `a + 1` is.

Comment: references ARE lvalues.  `&` computes a pointer to an lvalue and has nothing to do with references, other than the fact it can be applied to a reference as a reference is an lvalue.  Your code applies `&` to a simple variable (not a reference), and is generally nonsense (your comment about swapping objects without copying makes no sense -- there's no way to copy an object without copying it).

Comment: Sorry but all your comments are irrelevant. I'm not asking why it doesn't work, I know why it doesn't work. I'm asking why such an operation is not permitted. The only answer I've had until now to "why aren't they variables" is "because they are not variables". Useful.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "I understand the risks in doing so" part? What do you think the risks would be if it were permitted?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Not all of them -- anonymous rvalue references are xvalues ;)

Comment: If the address of a variable was a variable, every time you accessed it would requiring an extra indirection.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Or, depending on how you design it, an infinite amount of extra indirections ;)

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Would it? To me this would be a compile time processing.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: It's not permitted because it's a nonsensical operation.  As pointed out in the first few comments, what would it mean to assign to a number (the address)?  If you want the compiler to automatically generate variables to store those numbers, where would you stop?  Would you generate variables for the variables for the variables for the variables to store the numbers?

Comment: Depends on what @BenjaminLindley means by "it".

Comment: @jamesdlin Okay, we have reached "Turtles all the way down". Question can be closed now :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: If so, then I have no idea what you would mean the operation `&a = &b` to actually do.

Comment: See my edit, and sorry for the troll, I didn't expect so many experts to jump on me :/

Comment: You just have the syntax wrong. You can have pointers to pointers that allow you to swap pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to change the address of an object, right? That is impossible. Every object has a fixed address through its entire lifetime. You cannot give a different address to an object, ever. The address of an object is implicit in the machine code that's generated, it's not stored anywhere per se.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you understood my question as well. For me, swapping two objects is nothing else than swapping their names in most cases. And since their name is only an artifact of the programming language, why would it not be possible to tell the compiler "Now John is Sarah, apply that from now on."?

Comment: There are no names in machine code. Names in programming languages are just convenient ways for programmers to avoid having to think about offsets. If "hans" can mean "object at address 0x1234" now and "object at address 0x5678" later, then hans' current address must be stored at some other non-moving place, so every machine instruction that needs to access hans can find out where he lives right now. Every access to hans would have to go through that additional indirection. Alternatively, you would have to rewrite every machine instruction that accesses hans. Kind of what a moving GC does :)

Comment: I really like your answer. But I'm not sure I agree; if there is a way to resolve "I want to access the variable named x" already, then, why would it not be possible that the compiler understood that a swap operation is equivalent to swapping the corresponding names in all such subsequent requests?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: How does the compiler know which requests are subsequent?  `if(rand() % 2) &a = &b; ++a;` -- How does the compiler resolve that without an extra indirection?

Comment: Because "all such subsequent requests" is a runtime question, not a compile-time question. If you call a function `foo` that does something with hans, and then change the address of hans and call `foo` again, the machine code of `foo` has to account for the fact that hans is now somewhere else; but the machine code is the same for the entire duration of the program, so it cannot magically access hans through an unknown, potentially changing address. It would have to load the current address from some other, fixed location; in other words, a pointer, an additional level of indirection.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, they were really what I wanted to know, maybe I should work on the way I ask my questions in the future, since so many people did not understood what I meant :/ I'd like to thank David and Omkant as well for their post, but I'm going to mark this one as the answer.

Comment: In effect, the compiler would have to detect that your code might ever use this feature on a variable and internally implement that variable as a pointer. It would also have to disable many optimizations in this case because of the risk of aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

`&` is an operator with a value as its result. How would you assign something to a value? Example:

```
int i, n;
i + n = 50;
```

Comment: @nhahtdh: The result of `a[1]` is a reference, not a temporary.

Comment: `&` does not return a temporary, it simply returns a value. Scalar temporaries are extremly rare :)

Comment: @FredOverflow What holds that value though? It's not a literal, so what is it? AFAIK, a value isn't something that can exist on it own. Well, I think :-P

Comment: Nothing needs to hold the value, it's just a value.

Comment: @FredOverflow But if there's nothing there (semantically I mean, in the semantics of the C++ language), then why is it possible to refer to it with: `int i, j; const int& nothing = i + j;`? Note that `nothing` is a reference. It needs an actual object to refer to, not just some abstract "value" that exists somewhere in hyperspace. :-)

Comment: Right, binding a scalar value to a reference is the only scenario I am aware of that involves the creation of a scalar temporary. But unless you bind a scalar value to a reference, no temporary is needed.

Comment: @FredOverflow Well, OK. But I hope we're talking C++ semantics here rather than compiler implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the top of your question :

`Why are pointers obtained by the address-of operator not lvalues?`

According to c99 standard,

```
ISO : c99 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
```

Semantics

`3

The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator,
neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the **result is not an lvalue**.`

And being a temporary is the property of an object.
When you create reference of an object then it's just the temporary and you can't redefine  the same for other variable.

Now in your case what you have done is `passing by address` not `passing by reference`.
For `pass by reference` just need to pass variable so no need of `&` there in calling environment.

simply do like this :

```
 swap(a,b); // calling

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
 // definition 
 // here a and b are reference.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, see my comment in FredOverflow's post :)

Answer (score 2):

There are already numerous other ways to do this, why should there be one more that's inferior to the others? You can do this perfectly with smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at least sb who understood the question. So then it comes to the interesting part, because obviously, if we we go with pointers, yes, this becomes trivial. My question is; variables are named quantities. The name is mainly for the compiler I assume, and values are stored at addresses. Since the name is transparent in there, why can't we dynamically reassign the name to another address in a program?

Comment: Because the language already provides a way for you to do that which is explicit and safer. Your question is, "Why doesn't it provide another, inferior way?" Is there one good reason it should?

Comment: So your answer is that using pointers and being careful to maintain existence of pointed memory through the whole processing scope is easier than a renaming instruction?

Comment: You have to do all the same things with your renaming instruction. And yes, it's harder because at least when you're dealing with a pointer, you know it. With this construction, you have to look at every single line of code that touches a variable to know whether it's being used like a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, see my comment in FredOverflow's post :)

Answer (score 1):

An object is a location in memory.
A variable name is a reference for an object (a way to refer to the object in the program). Not all variables have names though.

But you can achieve what you want by passing an alias to your variable:

```
void print(double& ref1, double& ref2)
{
    printf("%.4f %.4f\n", ref1, ref2);
}
int main()
{
    double a = 157648.13;
    double b = 96871.84;

    print(a, b);    
    print(b, a); // Pass them the function the other way around.
                 // You have effectively swapped the values (as far as the function is concerned).
}
```

In my option you are trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. This effectively simulates the behavior that I wanted. With this approach, one would have to enclose the processing following a swap in a new function, which can rapidly become annoying. Another solution that I prefer would be to enclose all processing data in a "pointers structure", pointers which would then be used for the processing instead of the actual (potentially large) variables, thereby ensuring efficient swaps when necessary. I agree, it's just an overhead, and the problem is solvable, just not solved by the language.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: You are missing the point. Name is an alias to an object. Just like a reference is an alias to an object. You have no need to swap the objects in the first place.

Comment: Nonsense. If I follow your logic, and if I exclude the solutions described in my previous comment, this would mean that code duplicates should be written where variable names are swapped. I'm sure this is not what you meant, but rather what I wrote in my previous comment; hide the swap operation behind a new "namespace" defined by the inputs of a function. Some may call this smart, but still, the word "hide" is in that last sentence.